# Focus textbox on main form after closing a second form

Tags: c#, winforms, textbox, focus

How do I focus a `TextBox` element on the main form after closing a second form which is opened by calling `ShowDialog()`?

I have tried to call `MainForm.TextBox.Focus()` in the closing and closed event of the second form, but this won't focus the textbox.

I am using `System.Windows.Forms` on the compact framework.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From your second form, make a button (or another control) return a [`DialogResult`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.dialogresult.aspx) by going into Properties. When you want the second form to close (ie after you press a button) make it return a specific `DialogResult`. In your main form you can do this:

```
if(secondform.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
{
    textBox.Focus();
    ...
}
```

Calling `ShowDialog()` will block until it is closed so you could simply do:

```
secondform.ShowDialog();
textbox.Focus()
```

However the first example is for when you only want to make the textbox have focus after you press a certain button or do an action on the second form.

Comment: Thanks this works. I can't vote up you as I need 15 rep. I can accept the answer in 5 mins.

Answer (score 3):

ShowDialog means, it's a modal window and the focus won't go back to main form until you close second form. You can set focus back in the same code which you used to open the second form.

```
SecondFrm.ShowDialog();
Textbox.Focus();
```

Answer (score 0):

ShowDialog() will only return when the second form is closed, so you can write `MyTextBox.Select()` right after the call.

Answer (score 0):

```
SomeForm form1 = new SomeForm();
form1.ShowDialog();
```

here you're  showing the new form.
When you close it, you will execute methods after that, so add

```
yourTextbox.Focus();
```

so, its:

```
SomeForm form1 = new SomeForm();
form1.ShowDialog(); // do what you want in your form, then close it
yourTextbox.Focus();
```

Comment: `SomeForm.ShowDialog()` should be changed to `form1.ShowDialog()`.