# c# Form Event like "GotFocus" / "Enter" or similar

Tags: c#, forms, visual-studio, events

I'm fighting with my C# forms.

I got 2 Forms in my tool. Let's say Main and Second.

I open Second via Main with Second.ShowDialog();
Main is now shown in backgound and is not useable.
After that I close Second over a button like Second.Close();

Now Main is shown again.
There is were my problem is at. 
I have to run a method in Main and would like to run it via an event.
But I just can't find any event which gets called after closing Second.

There is no "GotFocus" or "Enter"...
I tried things like "Shown" or "SetVisible" but they don't get triggered.

What can I do ?

Comment: here is the same problem which is posted before. i think you can use it to solve your issue. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11788628/focus-textbox-on-main-form-after-closing-a-second-form

Comment: That's not really what I'm looking for...

Comment: you can implement a observer pattern implementation then you find publish your message from second dialog to first one.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really understood the issue here, but maybe you should consider using UserControls in one form instead of ShowDialog if it fits your project requirements - That's how you can keep two views in one Frame context.

If you sticking with Frame to Frame navigation - there is a known pattern called messaging which gives you the ability of communication between different objects/instances/pages/frames, you can use it as well.